# Custom card or container with border, shape and three parts

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i create following flutter widget.

[image]

I want to use it in a column to navigate to the next page.

I've already tried a card or a container consisting of a row with three expandables. But either the red area with the icon overlaps the container with the rounded edges, or it is smaller than the container. What can I do or maybe someone has a code example?

Comment: you need to use `Card.clipBehavior` / `Container.clipBehavior`

Comment: @pskink Thanks for your tip with ```Container.clipBehavior```. That was the solution.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own custom widget.
Here's a code sample you could use:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double height;
  final Function onTap;

  MyWidget({this.height = 40.0, this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onTap(),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Icon(Icons.inbox, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                height: height,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                child: Text(
                  'ARCHIV',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.horizontal(right: Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              height: height,
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Try full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/1f3702a79e3e3008f14030cc3779da7a)

**Result:**
[image]